# Glide v3 to V4: toBytes() and transcode

Tags: android, byte, android-glide, migrate, transcode

How can I convert this to Glide v4. Much of our previous code depends on this bytes, so we need to keep it backward compatible.

```
 artRequestBuilder = Glide.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .asBitmap().toBytes()                    
             .transcoder(GlideUtils.getTranscoder(artType))
                    .signature(new StringSignature(Integer.toString(smallToken)));
```

There does not seem to be a Glide v4 solution. This would be a shame because it means behavior was just deprecated without a way to move to v4 without a total rewrite for folks with dependency on previous functionalities.

I have tried `.as(byte[].class)` but get an error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unhandled class: class [B, try .as*(Class).transcode(ResourceTranscoder)`

And there's no easy solution on how to add custom transcoders in v4.